# Disable access logs for GROBID

Tags: java, logging, grobid

I'm using GROBID as a Docker container. The default logging config is way to noisy for large scale production use, so I build a custom image based on the 0.7.2 version with just the grobid.yaml file replaced. The logging section of that file looks like this:

```
logging:
  level: CRITICAL
  loggers:
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont: "OFF"
    org.eclipse.jetty: "OFF"
    org.grobid: "OFF"
    io.dropwizard: "OFF"
    com.hubspot: "OFF"
    org.glassfish: "OFF"
  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: CRITICAL
      timeZone: UTC
```

It already troubled me that I had to set all those loggers to "OFF". They just ignored the configured log level, which makes the whole setup ridiculous, but perhaps I'm just missing something. So I disabled them, got much less logs (which proves that the file is used), but still get access logs.logging:
level: CRITICAL
loggers:
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont: "OFF"
org.eclipse.jetty: "OFF"
org.grobid: "OFF"
io.dropwizard: "OFF"
com.hubspot: "OFF"
org.glassfish: "OFF"
appenders:
- type: console
threshold: CRITICAL
timeZone: UTC

When processing millions of files I don't want to have millions of access log lines. Can anybody explain to me how to disable them?

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration file usually runs with INFO as log level.

The way to customize the configuration is to load it as volume as explained [here](https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Grobid-docker/#configure-using-the-yaml-config-file). Then you could modify the local config file and change `level` it to ERROR or `WARN` to minimize the messages you're going to receive.